# How to check for presence of scroll bars in TJvTreeView

Tags: delphi, scroll, treeview, jedi

I am trying to position something w.r.t. a TJvTreeView, and I would like to know both the width and presence of the vertical scroll view. Does anyone know the canonical way to do that? Or failing that, any way that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for the presence of the `WS_VSCROLL` window style:

```
HasVertScrollBar := (GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) and WS_VSCROLL) <> 0;
```

To find the width of system scroll bars, call `SystemParametersInfo` passing `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS`.

```
var
  ncm: TNonClientMetrics;
....
ncm.cbSize := SizeOf(ncm);
Win32Check(
  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ncm.cbSize, Pointer(@ncm), 0)
);
```

The scroll bar width can then be retrieved from `ncm.iScrollWidth`.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely solved the presence part of it. I am taking the width, by rough visual trial and error, to be 18, until I get a better way to work it out.

Comment: Oh. Didn't spot the width part. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to right. I got it to work by scanning through the Delphi library code and ended up with this:

    procedure CalcVerticalScrollBarWidth; // Based on code in vcl.menus TMenuItem.MeasureItem
    var
      NonClientMetrics: TNonClientMetrics;
    begin
      NonClientMetrics.cbSize := NonClientMetrics.SizeOf;
      if SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, 0, @NonClientMetrics, 0) then
      begin
        VerticalScrollBarWidth := NonClientMetrics.iScrollWidth;
      end;
    end;

Comment: My attempts to format that didn't work, then I ran out of editing time. I was hoping to add this at the start of that code:

    VerticalScrollBarWidth: integer = 17;